# "At level 0 using cached accessor for..." databinding warning in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm debugging someone's WPF UserControl (let's call it MyUserControl), which basically just has a `TextBlock` and a `Button`.

MyUserControl appears in a `Menu`, i.e. the `MenuItem`'s ItemTemplate will use it for displaying its items:

```
<MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <controls:MyUserControl />
            </MenuItem.Header>                              
        </MenuItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
```

And MyUserControl's XAML looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
             mc:Ignorable="d"              
             d:DesignHeight="80" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <!-- date and time at the top of the menu item -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Time, StringFormat={}{0:t}}" Foreground="Black"/>
        <!-- details button -->
        <Button Content="Click Me" Command="{Binding MyCommand, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The menu items are databound to an `ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>`, where MyViewModel just has a couple of public properties, a `DateTime` property called Time and a `RelayCommand` called MyCommand:

```
public class MyViewModel : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase
{
    public MyViewModel ()
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now;
        MyCommand = new RelayCommand( ExecuteMyCommand);
    }

    private void ExecuteMyCommand()
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "HI");
    }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand MyCommand { get; set; }
}
```

MyCommand is temporarily implemented like this as a simple test.

**The problem is that the Time databinding works fine, but the RelayCommand binding does not.**  When I put a breakpoint inside of ExecuteMyCommand and click the button, it doesn't get hit.

[image]

Also, when I click on the button, I get the following warning in the output window:

System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=9995714):   At level 0 using cached accessor for MyViewModel.MyCommand: RuntimePropertyInfo(MyCommand)

It sounds like since this is a warning, it might not indicate why the button click handler isn't executing, so is there anything else I can try?

Here's what ends up in the output window from the diagnostics trace:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=16825): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=16825): Found data context element: Button (hash=622526) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=16825): Activate with root item MyViewModel (hash=59763145)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=16825):   At level 0 using cached accessor for MyViewModel.MyCommand: RuntimePropertyInfo(MyCommand)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=16825): Replace item at level 0 with MyViewModel (hash=59763145), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(MyCommand)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=16825): GetValue at level 0 from MyViewModel (hash=59763145) using RuntimePropertyInfo(MyCommand): RelayCommand (hash=35966181)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=16825): TransferValue - got raw value RelayCommand (hash=35966181)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=16825): TransferValue - using final value RelayCommand (hash=35966181)
```

Maybe this is something in the MvvmLightToolkit's RelayCommand, and not actually a databinding error, after all?

**UPDATE**

I have also tried the following approach, which is to remove the `DataTemplate`, forego usage of the extra button and instead apply an `ItemContainerStyle` to the MenuItem, so that the command handler executes when the time is clicked:

```
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Time}" />
    </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Again, while Time works, the command does not.

Comment: It's a warning, i don't think it necessarily implies that anything is wrong here.

Comment: Also, if this does not work, you should explain how so and might want to post the code of the bound property's implementation.

Comment: @H.B. Thanks, I have updated my post with MyViewModel and sample output to show the Time databinding working properly.

Comment: This looks like it should work just fine, really...

Comment: `diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` is what's causing those Warning/BindingExpression things. It's a debugging aid. "Warning" is just a string it puts on each line

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes, I added it to try to understand what could be going wrong with the databinding.

Comment: @Dave Oh, sorry -- I misunderstood the title of your question. My bad.

Comment: @H.B. Thanks, I made the change to the ItemTemplate.  So, if you think what I have should work, can you think of any other debugging strategies?  I'll update my post with everything from the trace.

Comment: Well, see my answer. Not sure if there any good strategies for debugging this scenario. People run into this a fair bit.

Comment: @H.B. updated my post again -- I went away from the `MenuItem` within the `DataTemplate` and instead used the `ItemContainerStyle`, but same result...

Comment: Well, that's odd...

Comment: Would check if something is up with the command itself, maybe do a simple ad-hoc `ICommand` implementation to test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

The `ItemTemplate` should *not* contain a `MenuItem`, that is already created as container around the contents of the `DataTemplate`. It messes with click handling. The binding probably works just fine.

Having an additional button inside the `MenuItem` might also prove problematic (the click might be handled by the `MenuItem` and never reach the button). Usually `MenuItems` should just contain text.

Comment: Interesting!!!  I will look into the button click being an issue in the MenuItem.  What you're saying does make sense.

Comment: Perhaps the right thing to do here is to remove the button, and then bind the clicking of the MenuItem to MyCommand?  i.e. get rid of the UserControl, because at this point it's no different than text in a normal MenuItem.

Comment: Quite possibly, yes.

Comment: Regarding your comment about `ItemTemplate` not containing a `MenuItem`, isn't that actually necessary, since I'm trying to set the template for a `MenuItem`'s `MenuItem`?  I must have not explained it properly before, but the menu the UserControl appeared in is actually a submenu.

Comment: The `ItemTemplate` of `MenuItem` *a* sets the header of all sub-items of item *a*.

Comment: If you need to go any deeper you will want to apply a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, which has its own `ItemsSource` for further sub-items.